# How do you gracefully end a Spark application prematurely?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want my spark application to end gracefully if I have an empty RDD. What is the best way to do this in scala?

When I just use:

`if (myRDD.isEmpty) { sparkSession.stop() }`

The Spark Application tries to continue and throws an `IllegalStageException`.

Do I need a `System.exit(0)` afterwards? Should I add a `return` afterwards?

Comment: Are you trying to use SparkContext after you closed it? Please post some more of the code so we can see what you are actually trying to do. You would usually only stop the spark context when the whole program is finished so I don't see why you would like to do it in an if statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sparkSession.stop()` would only invalidate the Spark session, but would not stop the job. That's why you're getting an `IllegalStageException`, as the job (still running!) tries to access an already invalidated session.

I'd recommend either using `return` or throwing an exception to end the job prematurely, it's safer than `System.exit(0)`

Comment: I'm new to scala/spark, so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but what makes System.exit(0) unsafe?

Comment: Not a dumb question, and the answer has nothing to do with Scala actually. Throwing an exception or using `return` passes control to the caller, whereas `System.exit()` terminates the application. If you're sure that you're running standalone, then using `System.exit()` is fine, although it's frowned upon; however, Spark applications, despite looking like standalone apps, are actually running as part of the Spark runtime on the cluster, and you might terminate more than you intended to. Take a look at the https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1446, for example.